# SQL forwarding Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, database

I use the forward engineering function of the MySQL Workbench, while this error occurs when creating table 'developedby'.

I didn't change the code generated by the workbench; see the source code below:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema Game_buying_db
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `Game_buying_db` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `Game_buying_db` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Game_buying_db`.`Customer`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Game_buying_db`.`Customer` (
  `cid` INT NOT NULL,
  `cname` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `cage` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ccity` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cid`));


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Game_buying_db`.`Developer`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Game_buying_db`.`Developer` (
  `did` INT NOT NULL,
  `dname` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `demail` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `dcity` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`did`));


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Game_buying_db`.`Game`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Game_buying_db`.`Game` (
  `gid` INT NOT NULL,
  `gname` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` INT NOT NULL,
  `publishdate` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`gid`));


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Game_buying_db`.`DevelopedBy`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Game_buying_db`.`DevelopedBy` (
  `gid` INT NOT NULL,
  `did` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`gid`, `did`),
  INDEX (`did` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT ``
    FOREIGN KEY (`gid`)
    REFERENCES `Game_buying_db`.`Game` (`gid`),
  CONSTRAINT ``
    FOREIGN KEY (`did`)
    REFERENCES `Game_buying_db`.`Developer` (`did`));
```

As I checked, the data type related in the foreign key declaration is consistent, so there might be some other problems here.

Please help!

Comment: Which error occurs exactly?

Comment: on the first `CONSTRAINT` of Developedby

Comment: It would be simpler just to show the error message you get as is, anyway...

Answer (score 0):

I think that '`gid`' or '`did`' datatype in `developedBy` table are not the same as primary keys in reference tables .. you need to check the datatype for them and make sure you are using the same datatype, may the primary keys datatype  is `INT UNSIGNED`

Comment: Problem solved, reason is that there is no alias for the constraint. Though I have no clue how to avoid this problem next time, where to add such an alias in the ER diagram?

Comment: CONSTRAINT `` looks invalid, put a name or just remove  this part.